# Plausible reason why Santa and his elves would start a military force?

Tags: military, santa-claus

So, I’m doing a story we’re my main character accidentally injured Santa Claus in a hunting accident. Him and his friends have to fill in and deliver all the gifts. He messes up, ***Badly*** and ends up over restricted air space. He is captured and sentenced to prison, and their is no escape. Until the X-MAS Force busts in, knock out all the guards and rescue them. They have helicopters, missiles, AKs, all the best toys. They get out of prison and deliver the gifts on time. Their is just one problem. So I’ve tried to think but can’t find the answer. Why would the Santa and his elves organize an army?

- The Elf army is about 10,000 men strong, and have three branches. The Army, Air Force, and X-MAS force.

Comment: Security and self-defence. Santa & eleves are effectively a super-rich economic entity. They also possess the world's fastest & most effective transport system. So, of course, evil-doers & nation states will want to get their greedy paws on the golden goodies. A miliary arm of Claus etc is a natural.

Comment: “…knock out all the guards and rescue them” Why should they rescue the guards? By the way, you are repeatedly confusing “their” and “there”. And I suppose “we’re” should be “where”.

Comment: @Holger: They rescue the Santa substitutes

Comment: The film Arthur Christmas addresses this idea handily. There's a massive expeditionary force that deploys every Christmas, and a nearly equally ops division at home base.  See also the military might in Santa vs the Snowman.

Answer (score 5):

### Amazon's invasion of the North Pole is inevitable.

The biggest risk to Santa and his Elves is competition in the form of megacorporations. At any point they could send a private army of Assault Drones and highly trained Combat Deliverymen in an attempt to destroy the only thing stopping them the company from a worldwide monopoly of international delivery.

So it naturally makes sense for there to be three branches:

**Elven Army** to deal with enemy ground forces

**Elven Air-Force** to deal with enemy aircraft

but of course there's another key point for the third branch:

### Even the children living in ISIS territory need to receive their Presents

And this is what I would assume **X-MAS is utilised for**. They're the external team of deniable operators responsible for high-risk missions in hostile territory. They take the presents and are dropped in, delivering the gifts before escaping without a single soul knowing they were ever there.

Because of their skillset, this team is also called upon to deal with any international incidents, such as the one you described in your question.

Answer (score 3):

**Santa is Odin, and his place at the North Pole is Valhalla.**

https://norse-mythology.org/cosmology/valhalla/

> The dead who reside in Valhalla, the einherjar, live a life that would
>   have been the envy of any Viking warrior. All day long, they fight one
>   another, doing countless valorous deeds along the way. But every
>   evening, all their wounds are healed, and they are restored to full
>   health.

If you are going to fight each other all day long, you will need weapons and armies and so that is what they have.

Valorous deeds include the making of sweet toys.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there's other people trying to get in on his game and he needs to protect himself from them. his army could be funded by loose change the elves find in people's couches while Santa delivers gifts. 7.442 billion people, that's a lot of loose change. It adds up. He could also have an army because different governments around the world either want him gone, believing him to be a threat, or they want the technology/magic that helps him do his job. The Elf Armed Forces aren't an army as much as they're a protection/deterrent. That's just two ideas, I'm sure someone else could have more ideas that are better.